# python: manipulating the global name space vs explicit assignment of object reference

Tags: python, variables, namespaces, global

I've been reading plenty of posts here stating that one should never manipulate the global namespace. I understand the concerns WRT good coding practice (I.e., keep things localized where you can, avoid side effects etc., etc.). But many comments also point to issues WRT performance (i.e. that doing so bloats the globals dict). However, I am curious whether the following two cases are indeed treated differently by the python interpreter

```
# let's assume the following two classes
class someclass1():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.n = name

class someclass2():
    def __init__(self,name):
        import builtins
        self.n = name
        setattr(builtins,name,self) 

# now we create the instances as
SC1 = someclass1("SC1")
someclass2("SC2")
```

Both versions will create new object handles (SC1 and SC2) in the global namespace. Does it truly matter how I create them? Note, I am fully aware that this can be handled by a dict but let's keep the discussion of why I want to do this for another thread.